# Meteor update issue when I update from 1.8 to 1.9.3

Tags: meteor, updates

NODE version : 12.16.1

```
meteor update --release 1.9.3
```

Below is the error display on console while running above command.

```
/Users/hussain/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.9.0.13fz1wq.uluf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node[1869]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:649:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
[1]    1869 abort 

 meteor update --release 1.9
```

Comment: I am facing same while updating meteor version to 1.9.3

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest (1.10.x) directly?

Comment: getting same issue while updating to 1.10.x

Comment: Try a `meteor reset` before